# Retrieve BillId from VendorPayment Record in Netsuite

Tags: search, netsuite

I need to retrieve the BillId, for which payment is made. But the VendorPayment Record type has no billId. How to retrieve billId for which the payment is made?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **createdfrom** field in Vendor Payment record

Comment: There is no field called **createdfrom** in VendorPayment Record. I have referenced the schema browser in following link [link] (https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/SchemaBrowser/indexv2012_2_0.html). correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Check this https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/RecordsBrowser/2012_2/Records/vendorpayment.html

Comment: Further more, Don't blindly trust NS Documentation. A solution may work even if its not according to NS Documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code:

```
var id = '100'; //Your vendor payment record
var record = nlapiLoadRecord('vendorpayment', id);
var createdFrom = record.getFieldValue('createdfrom'); //This is the ID of the transaction where the vendor payment was created from.
```

Or you can create a saved search and add some filtering method in the code to retrieve the associated transaction.